# what is "Google resource picker" in google smart device manager (SDM) test cases

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, nest-api, google-sdm-api

There's a set of test cases my app needs to pass as part of applying for Google device access's "commercial production" account. For test case 1.4 below I don't know what "Google resource picker" is:

[image]

Anyone know what that is or can point me to some documentation about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource Picker is a service that lets the end users manage access in regard to their specific resources (structure, device).

And the whole connection flow where users understand exactly what product and structure they select to connect

Which is now also the **Partner Connections Manager**, you can read more from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/authorization#partner-connections-manager-pcm)